# gcc-multilib not found but gcc is installed Mac M1

Tags: docker, gcc

gcc is installed.

while building docker image got the error

```
#0 4.414 Package gcc-multilib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#0 4.414 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#0 4.414 is only available from another source
#0 4.414
#0 4.453 E: Package 'gcc-multilib' has no installation candidate
```

any idea?

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile and the command you're using to build your image. You probably need to make sure you're 1. building for the intended platform and 2. are installing the right dependencies in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

removing gcc-multilib from the docker file worked for me I don't know why both gcc and gcc-multilib was there.